# How to create a Dual audio movie in any video fomat?

Tags: video, audio

I have some good collection of movies in some different formats. I want to make them in dual audio so which software  will be used to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the movies have the same length - e.g. DVD rips in various languages, then it should be possible to extract the audio stream from one and add it to other one using tools like VirtualDubMod or Avidemux. Did not try yet but my friend successfully used Avidemux for it. Big advantage is that you do not have to recompress the video - you can work in "Copy" mode. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Video editing programs such as Vegas,
>   Final Cut Pro and Avid Media composer
>   can do this. Basic programs like
>   Windows Movie Maker and iMovie do not
>   have this facility.

[SOURCE](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_make_dual_audio_movies)